# How to delay React routing while api is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

- I have multiple routes, by default app open in `"/login"` endpoint which renders `<Loginpage />`
- when I enter username and password the code in `<Loginpage />`
  validates the credentials with the api it is fetching from localhost,
- Now when I am seeing `<LoginPage />` and click submit, I am seeing
  immediate url changing and later seeing data manipulating acc to
  activeuser state.

**What I want**

- But, I want to render `<Loading/>` component when the api is being
  fetched, as soon it fetches I want to redirect to homepage endpoint

  And also, `<NavbarModule />` should be rendered in create bill and homepage components, but I don't want it in `<Loginpage />`, for this I came up with a solution by placing `<NavbarModule/>` in both create bill and homepage routes, But I feel its bit repeating code, Help me with these 2 problems

```
function App() {
  const [activeUser, setActiveuser] = useState([]);
  const [isloading, setIsloading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <section className="slit-app--section">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="login" />} />
          <Route
            excat
            path="login"
            element={<LoginPage setActiveuser={setActiveuser} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="homepage"
            element={
              <>
                <NavbarModule />
                <BillsModule activeUser={activeUser} />
                <ExtraFeaturesModule activeUser={activeUser} />
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="createbill"
            element={
              <>
                <NavbarModule />
                <CreateBill />
              </>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
function LoginPage({ props, setActiveuser }) {
  const usernameInput = useRef(null);
  const passwordInput = useRef(null);

  function submitClick() {
    // extract the input values
    const usernameValue = usernameInput.current.value;
    const passwordValue = passwordInput.current.value;

    // fetch data
    const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8889/api/v1/slitapp";
    axios
      .get(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        // slits contain array of 5 objects
        const { slits } = response.data.data;

        // find if the given username input is in slits data
        const foundUser = slits.find((user) => user.username === usernameValue);
        if (foundUser?.password === passwordValue) {
          setActiveuser(foundUser);
        } else {
          setActiveuser([]);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <section className="login_page_section ">
      <div className="loginPage">
        <h2 className="login_heading">Login</h2>
        <form>
          <input
            className="Login_slitID_input"
            placeholder="SLitID"
            type="text"
            ref={usernameInput}
          />
          <input
            className="Login_password_input"
            placeholder="Password"
            type="text"
            ref={passwordInput}
          />
          <NavLink
            to="/homepage"
            onClick={submitClick}
            className="login_submit_button"
          >
            submit
          </NavLink>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Comment: Seems like [a lot of previous content on this](/search?q=%5Breact-router%5D+asynchronous+routing), how do those various answers not apply here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  props here , you can keep the loading state inside the `<login/>` Component,

```
import { Link , useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();

const [isloading, setIsloading] = useState(false);
 function submitClick() {
// extract the input values

setIsloading(true);
const usernameValue = usernameInput.current.value;
const passwordValue = passwordInput.current.value;

// fetch data
const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8889/api/v1/slitapp";
axios
  .get(apiUrl)
  .then((response) => {
    // slits contain array of 5 objects
    const { slits } = response.data.data;

    // find if the given username input is in slits data
    const foundUser = slits.find((user) => user.username === 
    usernameValue);
    if (foundUser?.password === passwordValue) {
      setActiveuser(foundUser);

     setIsloading(false);
    navigate ('/homepage');
    } else {
      setActiveuser([]);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```

}

Comment: And for the <NavbarModule /> , you can pass it as a prop , maintaining one of the component as a parent component.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react';
    
function LoginPage({ props, setActiveuser }) {
      const usernameInput = useRef(null);
      const passwordInput = useRef(null);
      const navigate=useNavigate();
    
      function submitClick() {
        // extract the input values
        const usernameValue = usernameInput.current.value;
        const passwordValue = passwordInput.current.value;
    
        // fetch data
        const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8889/api/v1/slitapp";
        axios
          .get(apiUrl)
          .then((response) => {
            // slits contain array of 5 objects
            const { slits } = response.data.data;
    
            // find if the given username input is in slits data
            const foundUser = slits.find((user) => user.username === usernameValue);
            if (foundUser?.password === passwordValue) {
              setActiveuser(foundUser);
            } else {
              setActiveuser([]);
            }
          setTimeout(() => {
            navigate("/homepage"});
          }, 1000);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
          });
      }
    
      return (
        <section className="login_page_section ">
          <div className="loginPage">
            <h2 className="login_heading">Login</h2>
            <form>
              <input
                className="Login_slitID_input"
                placeholder="SLitID"
                type="text"
                ref={usernameInput}
              />
              <input
                className="Login_password_input"
                placeholder="Password"
                type="text"
                ref={passwordInput}
              />
              <button
                to="/homepage"
                onClick={submitClick}
                className="login_submit_button"
              >
                submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </section>
      );
    }
    
    export default LoginPage;
    javascriptreactjsreact-router
```

Comment: Instead of using NavLink use button then After you get response useNavigate to navigate 'hamepage' after 1000ms.

Comment: This helps to me delay in routing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Navigation links, e.g. the `Link` and `NavLink` components, will effect a navigation action ***immediately*** when clicked. This is why you see the UI change routes to the `"/homepage"` route ***and then*** later the `submitClick` processes the authentication and updates the `activeUser` state in the parent `App` component.

Instead of rendering and using a link to initiate the declarative navigation action *and* authentication flow at the same time you should wait until authentication has completed to issue an imperative navigation action. Replace `NavLink` with a regular button, and use the `useNavigate` hook to access the `navigate` function to issue the redirect to `"/homepage"` when authentication completes.

LoginPage

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function LoginPage({ setActiveUser, setIsLoading }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submitClick = (e) => {
    // Don't submit the form!
    e.preventDefault();

    // extract the input values from form submit event
    const usernameValue = e.target.SLitID.value;
    const passwordValue = e.target.Password.value;

    // Start loading
    setIsLoading(true);

    // fetch data
    const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8889/api/v1/slitapp";
    axios
      .get(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        // slits contain array of 5 objects
        const { slits } = response.data.data;

        // find if the given username input is in slits data
        const foundUser = slits.find((user) => user.username === usernameValue);

        setActiveUser(
          foundUser?.password === passwordValue ? foundUser : []
        );

        // Redirect to home page
        navigate("/homepage", { replace: true });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        // Clear loading
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <section className="login_page_section ">
      <div className="loginPage">
        <h2 className="login_heading">Login</h2>
        <form onSubmit={submitClick}> // <-- submit form
          <input
            className="Login_slitID_input"
            name="SLitID"
            placeholder="SLitID"
            type="text"
          />
          <input
            className="Login_password_input"
            name="Password"
            placeholder="Password"
            type="text"
          />
          <button
            type="submit" // <-- form submit button
            className="login_submit_button"
          >
            submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Pass `setActiveUser` and `setLoading` to `LoginPage`.

```
function App() {
  const [activeUser, setActiveUser] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <section className="slit-app--section">
      {isloading && /* render loading indicator/spinner/etc */}
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="login" />} />
          <Route
            path="login"
            element={(
              <LoginPage
                setActiveUser={setActiveUser}
                setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="homepage"
            element={
              <>
                <NavbarModule />
                <BillsModule activeUser={activeUser} />
                <ExtraFeaturesModule activeUser={activeUser} />
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="createbill"
            element={
              <>
                <NavbarModule />
                <CreateBill />
              </>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```